# How can I find limits without L'Hopital's Rule?

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

My question is, how can I evaluate limits without L'Hopital's Rule ?

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(\sqrt[3]{x})}{1-\cos x}$$

Comment: I remember this question was also asked yesterday. Moreover, I even answered that one...

Comment: @Guus, link for duplicate? Very likely to be homework.

Comment: @Ennar It looks like it is deleted because it doesn't show up in my "answered" list anymore. Time spent for nothing...

Comment: @Guus, even more likely to be homework.

Comment: There is also [this recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2960089/how-can-i-solve-these-trigonometric-limits-without-using-lhopitals-rule). And [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2958979/without-using-lhospital-rule-or-series-expansion-find-lim-x-to0-fracx-x-c/2958981#2958981) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2958258/finding-lim-x-to-0-sin-x-sin7x-without-lhopitals-rule).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For small $x$, $1-\cos x= 2\sin^2\frac{x}{2}\approx\frac{x^2}{2}$ while $\sin\sqrt[3]{x}\approx\sqrt[3]{x}$, so $\frac{\sin\sqrt[3]{x}}{1-\cos x}\approx 2x^{-5/3}$ diverges as $x\to 0$. Thus the limit is $\infty$.

Comment: I fail to see how using first-order Taylor approximation is not L'Hospital rule in a disguise. But it seems there's always this back and forth on MSE regarding this thing, so yeah, sure, why not.

Comment: @Ennar Saying $\sin x\approx x$ isn't a Taylor-series argument; it's a geometric observation that, if you cut a very small sector from a circle, almost all of the area is in the triangle with the same vertices.

Comment: It's not a Taylor-series argument if you prove $\lim_{x\to 0}(\sin x)/x = 1$ the way you describe. But, the notation $\approx$ leads me to think of Taylor's theorem.

Comment: @Ennar I just take $f(x)\approx g(x)$ to mean $f/g$ has limit $1$, regardless of how we prove it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

By standard limits we have that

$$\frac{\sin(\sqrt[3]{x})}{1-\cos x}=\frac{\sin(\sqrt[3]{x})}{\sqrt[3]{x}}\frac{x^2}{1-\cos x}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}}{x^2}$$

and

- $\frac{\sin(\sqrt[3]{x})}{\sqrt[3]{x}}\to 1$
- $\frac{x^2}{1-\cos x}\to 2$

and

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}}{x^2}=+\infty$$

Note also that if we extend the existence of $\sqrt[3]{x}$ to the values $x<0$ we have

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}}{x^2}=-\infty$$

Answer (score -1):

Write your term in the form
$$\frac{\sin(\sqrt[3]{x})(1+\cos(x))}{\sqrt[3]{x}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}}\cdot \frac{1}{x^2}$$

and you will see that the limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score -1):

You can evaluate limits without L'Hospital rule using known properties of limits:

- $\lim_{x\to c}(f(x) + g(x)) = \lim_{x\to c}f(x)+\lim_{x\to c}g(x)$
- $\lim_{x\to c}(f(x)g(x)) = (\lim_{x\to c}f(x))\cdot (\lim_{x\to c} g(x))$
- $\lim_{x\to c}(f(x)/g(x)) = (\lim_{x\to c}f(x))/ (\lim_{x\to c} g(x))$

provided that all the limits exist (and denominator is not $0$ in the last one).

It can also help to use change of variables for limits:

- If $\lim_{x\to a} g(x) = b$ and $g(x) \neq b$ on $B(a,\varepsilon)\setminus\{a\}$, then $\lim_{x\to a}f(g(x)) = \lim_{y\to b}f(y)$.

Finally, you will hardly get anywhere without using known limits such as $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$ and similar. You must have seen some kind of list of this kind.

Good luck with your limits!